# how to install software application from local server to client

Tags: client-server, chocolatey

I need to know when we are downloading a software application to install to our machine from chocolatey cloud repository, to where it's downloading (there is no exe file showing after it downloaded). **Without downloading an exe how it's installing to our machine. What kind of a process happening there?**

**The biggest problem** is after I install a software application to my local server machine, can I install those software application to client machines which are needed to install those software from local server machine, without directly installing from chocolatey cloud. Because each and every time when I needed some software application to install I have to download it from chocolatey cloud, it will wasting my bandwidth. So **I need to do after install to local server once, need to get from there**. Is that possible to do to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you asked on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Lak5han/status/654856372517933056) as well. Gary's answer is good, I would add that if you want to see where the exe files are downloading to, you can use the `-dv` switches to get quite a bit more information and/or inspect the Chocolatey log files.

For more detail about what you want to do, I'm understanding that you want to be able to not use Chocolatey.org or the internet at all for internal machines. Almost every business I talks to has this requirement, and we totally agree that you should not ever give away trust/control to the internet as a business: http://www.slideshare.net/ferventcoder/chocolatey-and-puppet-managing-your-windows-software-since-2011/9. I'll restate it here though. If you are a business, you should not use Chocolatey.org for packages because you are giving up control over when pkgs are updated, and whether packages break due to the changing internet. You are also placing trust in the internet. Both of those are pretty much no no's for any business worth their salt using something like Chocolatey in a production scenario. We also mention this on the [About page of Chocolatey.org](https://chocolatey.org/about).

Instead, when businesses use Chocolatey, they usually download the package and the files that the package usually reaches out to the internet for. Then they edit the package itself to point to those internal files. They then take those edited packages and place them on an [internal repository.](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/How-To-Host-Feed) All of the computers in their network point to that internal repository and the default chocolatey.org source is disabled.

That process does take some time, which is why we are working on Chocolatey for business with something that would help that become a simple command and eventually a button click for businesses.

Comment: after exe downloaded, how its getting install without user interaction (atlease without no .ps1 file). i mean how its selecting the option and go to next step.

Answer (score 0):

By default, assuming that the required exe/msi is not contained within the Chocolatey Package directly, Chocolatey will download the required exe/msi from the internet, and place it into the `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey` folder.  However, this Cache Location is configurable, and you can set it to anything you want.

Run the command, `choco config -h` for more information on how to set the Cache Location.

There was a project that aimed to handle the situation that you are describing here:

https://github.com/BahKoo/ChocolateStore

But I notice that it hasn't been updated in a while, so you might want to do some tests on it first to make sure that it is still functioning how you expect.

Comment: ##Can you please tell me in detail how to do that? When I run tis in side bin folder ChocolateStore M:\Store http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/GoogleChrome/  it gave me a error message by telling “'ChocolateStore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.”
##What are the arguments That I need to pass?

##And can you let me know where do I need to put this “ChocolateStore <directory> <url>” and what are the parameters do I need to insert (especially for <url>)
##What is Ionic.Zip. what is that doing?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used the ChocolateStore application, I am just aware of it's existence.  I would suggest that you ask any questions that you have in the Issues section of the GitHub repository, and hopefully the creator will be able to help you.

Comment: I pretty much answered this on Twitter, but I will follow up here. My answer is a bit different, so I may answer this as a different answer.